# Program not writing to list from while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to write values to my VideoFlag list when the pixel intensity difference is higher than a predefined threshold. On output however my output 'flag.txt' file is empty, and I'm not sure why. Does anyone know in what way my code is wrong?

Thanks!

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

MIList =[]
VideoFlag=[]

def frame_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame):
    diff_frames1 = cv2.absdiff(next_frame, cur_frame)

    diff_frames2 = cv2.absdiff(cur_frame, prev_frame)

    return cv2.bitwise_and(diff_frames1, diff_frames2)

def get_frame(cap):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        scaling_factor = 1
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = scaling_factor, fy = scaling_factor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        return cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

def moving_average(MIList, n=30) :
    ret = np.cumsum(MIList, dtype=float)
    ret[n:] = ret[n:] - ret[:-n]
    return ret[n - 1:] / n

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    selectedvideo = askopenfilename()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(selectedvideo)
    length = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    intlength = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    currentframenumber = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    intcurrentframenumber = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
    scaling_factor = 1
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter((selectedvideo + 'motionindexed.avi'),fourcc, 60.0, (640,478), isColor=False)
    with open((selectedvideo + 'threshold' + '.txt'), 'r') as readthreshold:
        threshold = float(readthreshold.readline())

    prev_frame = get_frame(cap)
    cur_frame = get_frame(cap)
    next_frame = get_frame(cap)

    while (cap.isOpened()):

        try:
            cv2.imshow("Object Movement", frame_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame))
            prev_frame = cur_frame
            cur_frame = next_frame
            next_frame = get_frame(cap)
            differencesquared = (next_frame-cur_frame)**2
            interframedifference = np.sum(differencesquared)
            MIList.append(interframedifference)
            print(interframedifference)
            if interframedifference >= threshold:
                out.write(cur_frame)
                VideoFlag.append(str(intcurrentframenumber + '|' + 1))
                print(VideoFlag)
            elif interframedifference < threshold:
                VideoFlag.append(str(intcurrentframenumber + '|' + 0))
                print(VideoFlag)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
        except:
            break

    with open((selectedvideo + 'flag' + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
        for item in VideoFlag:
            f.write(str(item))


    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this is called if this code was not imported ... ie it was directly run
    # if this is called, that means there is no GUI already running, so we need to create a root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    main()
```

Comment: it doesn't need to be closed, because I'm using a 'with open as' statement, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Does `print(VideoFlag)` print something? If you are running this by double-clicking in a windows manager, it may be writing the file to a different directory than you think. `print(os.path.abspath(selectedvideo + 'flag' + '.txt'))` would show you the real file.

Comment: If you want the file to be overwritten each time you run this program, opening with "w" is the right choice.

Comment: Hi, the absolute path of my flag file looks as expected - however printing VideoFlag is displaying an empty list, so for whatever reason my code isn't appending properly into my list it doesn't seem

Comment: A liberal scattering of print statements to see if values are what you want is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing

```
with open((selectedvideo + 'flag' + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
    for item in VideoFlag:
        f.write(str(item))
```

with

```
# Note that you need to append('a') data to the file instead of writing('w') to it for each iteration. 
# The last line will be empty string and that is what contains finally.
with open((selectedvideo + 'flag' + '.txt'), 'a') as f: 
    for item in VideoFlag:
        f.write(str(item))
```

shall resolve the problem.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. The program writes the file one time after doing its calculations. By switching to append, user won't overwrite a value from a previous run... but that doesn't help solve the problem, it just leaves stale data.

Comment: odd, I would've assumed that would've fixed it too but the issue still exists - it's producing no output for my flag text file, and is not producing the output video either..

Comment: @KittenMittons what does `VideoFlag` print ?

Comment: literally nothing - I'm getting terminal output of '15412' once and then the program is finishing.. I wonder if my while loop isn't running properly

Comment: @KittenMittons - are you running it from the command line then very likely your problem is the while loop. For debug, pull your core processing out to a test file and cut the tkinter stuff out completely. Narrow it down as much as you can and debug that.

Comment: After some trial and error it seems that the program won't loop with the VideoFlag.append line included after my out.write() line. Anyone have any ideas why that may be?

Comment: try printing out the exception as there may be an exception in the try block.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved my problem - so for whatever reason it wasn't running due to my types in my append method - I'd forgotten to convert one of my integers to a string I think, I've reworked it and I think that's solved my issue! Cheers for the input guys!

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def frame_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame):
    diff_frames1 = cv2.absdiff(next_frame, cur_frame)

    diff_frames2 = cv2.absdiff(cur_frame, prev_frame)

    return cv2.bitwise_and(diff_frames1, diff_frames2)

def get_frame(cap):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        scaling_factor = 1
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = scaling_factor, fy = scaling_factor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        return cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    MIList = []
    VideoFlag = []
    selectedvideo = askopenfilename()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(selectedvideo)
    length = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    intlength = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    currentframenumber = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    intcurrentframenumber = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
    scaling_factor = 1
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter((selectedvideo + 'motionindexed.avi'),fourcc, 60.0, (640,478), isColor=False)
    with open((selectedvideo + 'threshold' + '.txt'), 'r') as readthreshold:
        threshold = float(readthreshold.readline())

    prev_frame = get_frame(cap)
    cur_frame = get_frame(cap)
    next_frame = get_frame(cap)

    while (cap.isOpened()):

        try:
            cv2.imshow("Object Movement", frame_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame))
            prev_frame = cur_frame
            cur_frame = next_frame
            next_frame = get_frame(cap)
            differencesquared = (next_frame-cur_frame)**2
            interframedifference = np.sum(differencesquared)
            MIList.append(interframedifference)
            print(interframedifference)
            if interframedifference >= threshold:
                out.write(cur_frame)
                VideoFlag.append((str(intcurrentframenumber) + ' ' + '|' + ' ' + '1' + '\n' ))


            elif interframedifference < threshold:
                VideoFlag.append((str(intcurrentframenumber) + ' ' + '|' + ' ' + '0' + ' \n'))



            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
        except:
            break

    with open((selectedvideo + 'flag' + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
        for item in VideoFlag:
            f.write((str(item) + '\n'))
        print(VideoFlag)


    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this is called if this code was not imported ... ie it was directly run
    # if this is called, that means there is no GUI already running, so we need to create a root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    main()
```